# How to get rid of "Some devices missing" in BTRFS after reuse of devices?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have been playing around with BTRFS on a few drives I had lying around. At first I created BTRFS using the entire drive, but eventually I decided I wanted to use GPT partitions on the drives and recreated the filesystem I needed on the partitions that resulted. (This was so I could use a portion of each drive as Linux swap space, FYI.)

When I got this all done, BTRFS worked a treat. But I have annoying messages saying that I have some old filesystems from my previous experimentation that I have actually nuked. I worry this meant that BTRFS was confused about what space on the drives was available, or that some sort of corruption might occur.

The messages look like this:

```
$ sudo btrfs file show
Label: 'x'  uuid: 06fa59c9-f7f6-4b73-81a4-943329516aee
    Total devices 3 FS bytes used 159.20GB
    devid    3 size 931.00GB used 134.01GB path /dev/sde
    *** Some devices missing

Label: 'root'  uuid: 5f63d01d-3fde-455c-bc1c-1b9946e9aad0
    Total devices 4 FS bytes used 1.13GB
    devid    4 size 931.51GB used 1.03GB path /dev/sdd
    devid    3 size 931.51GB used 2.00GB path /dev/sdc
    devid    2 size 931.51GB used 1.03GB path /dev/sdb
    *** Some devices missing

Label: 'root'  uuid: e86ff074-d4ac-4508-b287-4099400d0fcf
    Total devices 5 FS bytes used 740.93GB
    devid    4 size 911.00GB used 293.03GB path /dev/sdd1
    devid    5 size 931.51GB used 314.00GB path /dev/sde1
    devid    3 size 911.00GB used 293.00GB path /dev/sdc1
    devid    2 size 911.00GB used 293.03GB path /dev/sdb1
    devid    1 size 911.00GB used 293.00GB path /dev/sda1
```

As you can see, I have an old filesystem labeled 'x' and an old one labeled 'root', and both of these have "Some devices missing". The real filesystem, the last one shown, is the one that I am now using.

So how do I clean up the old "Some devices missing" filesystems? I'm a little worried, but mostly just OCD and wanting to tidy up this messy output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this out for myself. Maybe it will help someone else.

I poked around in the code to see what was going on. When the `btrfs filesystem show` command is used to show all filesystems on all devices, it scans every device and partition in `/proc/partitions`. Each device and each partition is examined to see if there is a BTRFS "magic number" and associated valid root data structure found at 0x10040 offset from the beginning of the device or partition.

I then used hexedit on a disk that was showing up wrong in my own situation and sure enough there was a BTRFS magic number (which is the ASCII string `_BHRfS_M`) there from my previous experiments.

I simply nailed that magic number by overwriting a couple of the characters of the string with "**", also using hexedit, and the erroneous entries magically disappeared!

Comment: It sounds like "Some devices missing" can be safely ignored, then.

Comment: Yes indeed. But people who find such things annoying or can't relax their OCD enough to let it go can do what I did (because I find such things annoying and cannot relax my own OCD).

Answer (score 1):

To wipe from disks that are NOT part of your wanted BTRFS FS, I found:

How to clean up old superblock ? 
...
To actually remove the filesystem use:

wipefs -o 0x10040 /dev/sda

8 bytes [5f 42 48 52 66 53 5f 4d] erased at offset 0x10040 (btrfs)"

from: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Problem_FAQ#I_can.27t_mount_my_filesystem.2C_and_I_get_a_kernel_oops.21